# kernel of linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T,S: V\to V$ be 2 linear transformations, and $\ker(T)=\{0\}$.
I need to prove why $\ker(T\circ S)=\ker(S)$.
I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: **Hint** In general, the way to show two sets $X,Y$ are equal is to show $X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\ker T = \{ 0 \}$, $T$ is injective. Therefore, $(T \circ S)v=0$ if and only if $Sv=0$.

[Both of these results require proofs, but I presume that you've either seen them before or can prove them yourself.]

Comment: Nice job pointing the way without doing it for him.

Comment: Im sorry but I didnt understand the last part

Comment: @user1816377: What about it don't you understand?

Comment: "Therefore, (T∘S)v=0 if and only if Sv=0."
I understand why S(v) has to $0$ so we get result $0$ but I dont understtand why the result is $ker(s)$ in every case

Comment: @user1816377: This is just a property of injective maps: if $f$ is *any* injective function and $f(x)=y$, then $f(z)=y$ if and only if $z=x$. Here, set $f=T$, $x=0$, $y=0$ and $z=Sv$.

Comment: but why its true for every vector in the $ker$ and not only for $0$?

Comment: @user1816377: The point is that $Sv=0$ if and only if $v \in \ker S$, by definition of the kernel. Likewise, $TSv=0$ if and only if $v \in \ker (T \circ S)$. So proving $\ker (T \circ S) = \ker S$ amounts to showing that: $TSv=0$ if and only if $Sv=0$. And this follows by injectivity of $T$, as I argued above.